# How to GetFiles from multiple different paths

Tags: c#, file, directory, directoryinfo, getfiles

Can we get files from different location using some Built-In Function in C# without any loop. Like if I have following paths

```
C:\Folder1
C:\abc\Folder2
D:\Folder3
```

I want to get all files from `Folder1`, `Folder2` and `Folder3` at same time without using any loop.

Comment: There is no API available for that. You need to aggregate files from different folders by either using LINQ, loops or something else.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? Even if you got all the files, the odds are you'd need to use a loop to actually use the file paths.

Comment: Why don't you want to use any loop?

Comment: I want to save these file locations in Microsoft SQL database by using BULK INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN, you can search for files in a single directory.

For example:

```
Directory.GetFiles("C:\Folder1")
```

You just need to adapt, however an extension method is not possible since it's a static class.

More info here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Basiccly, it means that a loop is required to do search for all the paths. Otherwise, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

A loop is required there is no built-in function for that.

You can maintain `List<string>` for the purpose.

Example:

```
List<string> lstPaths = new List<string>();
lstPaths.Add(@"C:\Folder1");
lstPaths.Add(@"C:\abc\Folder2");
lstPaths.Add(@"D:\Folder3");

foreach(string sPath in lstPaths)
{
    string[] arrFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sPath);

    //you can loop through arrFiles here
}
```